# How do I send cookies to the client when my response type is ModelAndView?

Tags: java, kotlin, cookies, micronaut

If I have a method that returns a `ModelAndView` (see example), but at the same time I also want to return cookie along with the rendered view, how do I do it?

```
@Get(produces = [MediaType.TEXT_HTML]) 
fun test() : ModelAndView<Map<String, Any>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the return type of your controller method to `MutableHttpResponse<ModelAndView<?,?>>` where the question marks you replace by whatever type you want, of course.

Micronaut is smart enough to understand that you are returning a "raw" `HttpResponse`, however it identifies the real type that you want to return, a `ModelAndView` in this case, so it will render your view AND set cookies or whatever other properties you've set in the `HttpResponse`.

Example of method signature:

```
@Get(produces = [MediaType.TEXT_HTML]) 
fun test() : MutableHttpResponse<ModelAndView<Map<String, Any>>>
```